# How to CFRelease a CGEventRef that must be returned?

Tags: xcode, macos, automatic-ref-counting, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I'm intercepting `CGEventRef`s in two ways:

- Returning value `NULL` to kill the event
- Assigning the event a new `CGEventRef` via `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent()`

Xcode's Analyzer tells me I have a potential leak when I create the new event. But I need to return that new event, so I can't `CFRelease` it there.

- Is this Xcode error valid?
- Where should I properly `CFRelease`ing the new CGEventRef that I create?
- In both the null and new event cases, I don't know if I need to release the former value of the event.
- Is appending "new" to the method name the correct way to fix this? I think it might be, for the case when I create a new event. But what of the other cases?

.

```
- (CGEventRef)modifySomeKeyboardEvents:(CGEventRef)event {

    CGKeyCode keycode = (CGKeyCode)CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode);
    NSLog(@"keycode: %d", keycode);

    switch (keycode) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"pressed 'a'");
            //Kill the event
            event = NULL;

            //Is a `CFRelease` of some kind needed here, to release the previous value?

            break;

        case 38:
            NSLog(@"pressed 'h'");

            //Send different character:
            CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
            CGEventRef newKeyEvent = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(eventSource, 1, true);
            CGEventSetIntegerValueField(newKeyEvent, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, 51); // keycode '51' = backspace
            CFRelease(eventSource);

            event = newKeyEvent;

            //Can't CFRelease here, but somewhere?
            //CFRelease(newKeyEvent);

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //Xcode error: "Potential leak of an object stored in newKeyEvent"
    return event;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `CGEventTapCallback` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH1g-BBCHIIJJ) says

> After the new event has been passed back to the event system, the new event will be released along with the original event.

Therefore you are *not* responsible for releasing the new event or the old event.

The analyzer doesn't know this, so you need to tell it.  You can silence the analyzer by putting `new` at the **beginning** of the method name, but maybe it would be clearer to use `copy`, which also silences the warning:

```
- (CGEventRef)copyOrModifyKeyboardEvent:(CGEventRef)event {
```

(I guess `newOrModifiedKeyboardEvent:` would work just as well.)

I believe the analyzer ought to flag this too, since it now fails to return a +1 reference count when you just return the input event.  But in my testing, it doesn't.  The Xcode 4.6.2 analyzer gives me no warnings for this method:

```
- (CGEventRef)copyOrModifyEvent:(CGEventRef)event {
    CGEventRef newEvent;
    if (CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode) == 38) {
        newEvent = CGEventCreate(NULL);
    } else {
        newEvent = event;
    }
    return newEvent;
}
```

Comment: The base `CGEventRef MyEventTapCallBack(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void *refcon)` function gives the same Xcode error. That's the function name used in the Apple docs... do you see the same error? Do I really need to also rename that `copy..`?

Comment: Yes, you need to rename that also.  It needs to start with `create` or `copy`.